# How to design a 500 khz sine wave generator?

Tags: oscillator, waveform

I need to design a 500 khz sine wave generator. Could anyone help?

Comment: What part do you need assistance with?

Comment: It will be best if you can post a circuit and give me some explanation. I understand that I should study the principle then design one myself, but for some reason I am in a rush now  :(

Comment: With no idea about your skills and current experience level this question is practically impossible to answer.  You should provide further details about exactly which bits you need help with.

Comment: I am an undergraduate electrical engineering student, year 4. I have play around a bit with the 555 timer and that all (I study more about programming, so not much about circuit design, specially analog) :(

Comment: It would help to edit that information into your user profile on the site.

Comment: We don't do *giv me da codz* type of questions here.

Comment: How accurate do your need your 500 KHz to be?  What can you tolerate in the way of overtone content?  How much power can you spend?  How much space?  How much money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the only frequency you want you could probably design one from scratch. But Analog Devices offers a wide range of DDS generator chips which you can program in serial and will produce any frequency from 0Hz to 300MHz with a less that 1HZ resolution.  (depending on the chip).

If you want to keep it simple you could use the AD9833, its only 10 pins and is easy to program with a PIC chip or similar.